# List out auto scaling group names with a specific application tag using boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, autoscaling

I was trying to fetch auto scaling groups with Application tag value as 'CCC'.

The list is as below,

```
gweb
prd-dcc-eap-w2
gweb
prd-dcc-emc
gweb
prd-dcc-ems
CCC
dev-ccc-wer
CCC
dev-ccc-gbg
CCC
dev-ccc-wer
```

The script I coded below gives output which includes one ASG without CCC tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling',region_name='us-west-2')

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()

ccc_asg = []

all_asg = response['AutoScalingGroups']
for i in range(len(all_asg)):
    all_tags = all_asg[i]['Tags']
    for j in range(len(all_tags)):
        if all_tags[j]['Key'] == 'Name':
                asg_name = all_tags[j]['Value']
        #        print asg_name
        if all_tags[j]['Key'] == 'Application':
                app = all_tags[j]['Value']
        #        print app
        if all_tags[j]['Value'] == 'CCC':
                ccc_asg.append(asg_name)

print ccc_asg
```

The output which I am getting is as below,

```
['prd-dcc-ein-w2', 'dev-ccc-hap', 'dev-ccc-wfd', 'dev-ccc-sdf']
```

Where as `'prd-dcc-ein-w2'` is an asg with a different tag `'gweb'`. And the last one `(dev-ccc-msp-agt-asg)` in the CCC ASG list is missing. I need output as below,

```
dev-ccc-hap-sdf
dev-ccc-hap-gfh
dev-ccc-hap-tyu
dev-ccc-mso-hjk
```

Am I missing something ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working with below script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling',region_name='us-west-2')

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()

ccp_asg = []

all_asg = response['AutoScalingGroups']
for i in range(len(all_asg)):
    all_tags = all_asg[i]['Tags']
    app = False
    asg_name = ''
    for j in range(len(all_tags)):
        if 'Application' in all_tags[j]['Key'] and all_tags[j]['Value'] in ('CCP'):
                app = True
        if app:
                if 'Name' in all_tags[j]['Key']:
                        asg_name = all_tags[j]['Value']
                        ccp_asg.append(asg_name)
print ccp_asg
```

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: `client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()` returns max 100 Auto Scaling Groups in a single API call. If you have more ASGs you must use pagination and call `describe_auto_scaling_groups` again with `nextToken` parameter, otherwise you will have incorrect results. See my answer that deals with this problem.

Comment: Yes! I saw your comment below. It really helped. Thank you :)

Answer (score 20):

In boto3 you can use [Paginators with JMESPath filtering](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html#filtering-results-with-jmespath) to do this very effectively and in more concise way.

From boto3 docs:

> JMESPath is a query language for JSON that can be used directly on
>   paginated results. You can filter results client-side using JMESPath
>   expressions that are applied to each page of results through the
>   search method of a PageIterator.
>
> When filtering with JMESPath expressions, each page of results that is
>   yielded by the paginator is mapped through the JMESPath expression. If
>   a JMESPath expression returns a single value that is not an array,
>   that value is yielded directly. If the result of applying the JMESPath
>   expression to a page of results is a list, then each value of the list
>   is yielded individually (essentially implementing a flat map).

Here is how it looks like in Python code with mentioned `CCP` value for `Application` tag of Auto Scaling Group:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
)

filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(
    'AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format(
        'Application', 'CCP')
)

for asg in filtered_asgs:
    print asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michal, This really did the job. My above script was listing only asg names with Application as first tag. But your's listed all asg names with CCP tag. Really helpful :)

**One question. !!**
`PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}` .
What does this do ?
Is this a limit that we should set ?.

Regards,
Ashfaq

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on Michal Gasek's answer, here's an option that filters ASGs based on a dict of tag:value pairs.

```
def get_asg_name_from_tags(tags):
    asg_name = None
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
    while True:

        paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
        )
        filter = 'AutoScalingGroups[]'
        for tag in tags:
            filter = ('{} | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format(filter, tag, tags[tag]))
        filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(filter)
        asg = filtered_asgs.next()
        asg_name = asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
        try:
            asgX = filtered_asgs.next()
            asgX_name = asg['AutoScalingGroupName']
            raise AssertionError('multiple ASG\'s found for {} = {},{}'
                     .format(tags, asg_name, asgX_name))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return asg_name
```

eg:

```
asg_name = get_asg_name_from_tags({'Env':env, 'Application':'app'})
```

It expects there to be only one result and checks this by trying to use next() to get another. The StopIteration is the "good" case, which then breaks out of the paginator loop.

Comment: The above code works but for recent versions of python you will get the error `'generator' object has no attribute 'next'`. To solve the error use the `asg = next(filtered_asgs)` and `asgX = next(filtered_asgs)`.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this isn't via `describe_auto_scaling_groups` at all but [via `describe_tags`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_tags), which will allow you to make the filtering happen on the server side.

You can construct a filter that asks for tag application instances with any of a number of values:

```
Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'key',
            'Values': [
                'Application',
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'value',
            'Values': [
                'CCC',
            ]
        },
    ],
```

And then your results (in `Tags` in the response) are all the times when a matching tag is applied to an autoscaling group. You will have to make the call multiple times, passing back `NextToken` every time there is one, to go through all the pages of results.

Each result includes an ASG ID that the matching tag is applied to. Once you have all the ASG IDs you are interested in, *then* you can call `describe_auto_scaling_groups` to get their names.

Comment: I get this error when I tried your approach: "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeTags operation: Filter type MyCusstomTag is not correct. Allowed Filter types are: auto-scaling-group key value propagate-at-launch". Did you actually run your code?

Comment: It's been adapted to fit the question, but this way of making filters is exactly what I use in one of my applications. You aren't supposed to replace `key` and `value`; those strings have to be literal. `MyCusstomTag` would have to replace `Application` in the example I give.

Answer (score 1):

yet another solution, in my opinion simple enough to extend:

```
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

search_tags = {"environment": "stage"}

filtered_asgs = []

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()

for group in response['AutoScalingGroups']:

    flattened_tags = {
        tag_info['Key']: tag_info['Value']
            for tag_info in group['Tags']
    }

    if search_tags.items() <= flattened_tags.items():
        filtered_asgs.append(group)


print(filtered_asgs)
```