# Paginate and list out auto scaling group names with a specific application tag using boto3

Tags: boto3, autoscaling

I have already seen the suggested answer here:
[List out auto scaling group names with a specific application tag using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607381/list-out-auto-scaling-group-names-with-a-specific-application-tag-using-boto3)

However, it only processes the first 100 results.  It does not demonstrate how to process all the "pages".  I'm working in a large AWS environment and have two questions.

1. Is there no way to ask for JUST the asg's tagged with a certain string instead of parsing through everything in the environment?
2. If the answer to #1 is no - can someone help me understand how to paginate through all asg's until all have been checked for the tag in question?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
    asg_client = session.client('autoscaling')
    paginator = asg_client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
    asg_list = paginator.paginate()

    for x in asg_list:
        for asg in x['AutoScalingGroups']:
            for tag in asg['Tags']:
                if tag['Key'] == 'Solution':
                    print('ASG Name: '+ asg['AutoScalingGroupName'] + ' Tag: ' + tag['Value'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_autoscale_groups(region):

   client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=region)

   asg_name_list = []

   while True:
       paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
       page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
           PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 100}
       )
       for page in page_iterator:
           filtered_asgs = page_iterator.search(
               'AutoScalingGroups[] | [?contains(Tags[?Key==`{}`].Value, `{}`)]'.format(
            'SomeId', 'blah')
        )

           for asg in filtered_asgs:
               asg_name_list.append(asg['AutoScalingGroupName'])
       try:
           marker = page['Marker']
           print(marker)

       except KeyError:
           break

   print(asg_name_list)
```

Comment: This appears to work.  The try/except block is necessary or you can't get out of the "while true".  All in all it feels a little clumsy, but I'm not sure of a better way.  I'd be happy to get some advice on a more elegant way to do this.  I tried to access filtered_asgs via a print, but it just gives a spot in memory so given that I'm on a deadline, I threw in the asg_name_list.  Surely there's a better way...