# Lambda function to delete autoscaling groups with a specific tag using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, autoscaling

Below code lists all the auto-scaling groups. But is there a way I can get a list of all ASGs with a specific tag `state` and value is `undeployed`. And delete those autoscaling groups.

```
!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

client = boto3.client('autoscaling',region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()
    print(response)
```

I already tried this [List out auto scaling group names with a specific application tag using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607381/list-out-auto-scaling-group-names-with-a-specific-application-tag-using-boto3) but that looks outdated or maybe didn't work for me.

I tried multiple ways of filtering the tags, first at least to get the list of ASGs with that tag but the filtering with boto3 seems not similar to AWS CLI. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this (I didn't test it):

```py
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
  Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:state', 'Values': ['undeployed']}]
)


for group in response['AutoScalingGroups']:
  client.delete_auto_scaling_group(AutoScalingGroupName=group['AutoScalingGroupName'])
```

Or, you could filter the tags yourself in the Python code:

```py
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()

# Get ALL auto-scaling groups and filter them in code
for group in response['AutoScalingGroups']:
  tags = group['Tags']
  state_tag = [tag['Value'] for tag in tags if tag['Key'] == 'state']
  if state_tag and state_tag[0] == 'undeployed':
    # Delete the auto-scaling group here
    client.delete_auto_scaling_group(AutoScalingGroupName=group['AutoScalingGroupName'])
```

Here's what it is doing:

- Obtain a list of all auto-scaling groups
- Check whether there is a tag with a key of `state`
- If that tag has a value of `undeployed`, then delete the auto-scaling group